# Throwing with a previous frame information

Tags: javascript, exception, throw

```
function api(cmd) {
    if (cmd > 5) throw 'unknown command'
    console.log('executing the command', cmd)
}

api(2)
api(7)
```

If the above code is executed, this nice error message will be printed:

```
executing the command 2

test.js:2
        if (cmd > 5) throw 'unknown command'
                     ^
unknown command
```

How can I (can I?) get the error message go back one frame and display this instead:

```
executing the command 2

test.js:7
        api(7)
        ^
unknown command
```

Answer (score 1):

In many JavaScript environments you can get a complete stack of "ancestor" function calls (with their line numbers) when an error is raised, provided you raise the error with a proper `Error` object.

So change the code as follows:

```
 if (cmd > 5) throw new Error('unknown command');
```

Another possibility would be to change the way the function must be used. It could for instance return a function that must be called before anything happens:

```js
function api(cmd) {
    if (cmd > 5) return; // Return undefined
    // If all OK, return a function that does the job
    return function() {
       console.log('executing the command', cmd);
       // ....
    }
}

// The "contract" changed, so the caller must add parentheses:

api(2)()
api(7)() // TypeError: api() is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider just wrapping the statements with `try/catch` as follows, it will still not point to the exact line, but depends on your use it can be a close match and your function remain unchanged:

```
function api(cmd) {
        if (cmd > 5 ) throw `Unknown command: ${cmd}`;
        console.log('coommand', cmd);
    }

    try {
        api(3);
        api(10);
    } catch(e) {
        throw e;
    }
```